# Editing Hyperlinks Excel 2010 Macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Ok so I want to create a macro to replace a part of a hyperlink. I have tons of hyperlinks in the excel file. Is there a way to create a macro to do this.

---

For example

- www.OldName.com/
- www.Oldname.com/a/
- www.Oldname.com/b/

---

to

- www.NewName.com/
- www.NewName.com/a/
- www.Newname.com/b/

Comment: Are they Hyperlink formulas or Hyperlink objects?

Comment: Right click then edit hyperlink. Then they are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace your hyperlink, just change the addresses and strings:

```
Range("E1").Hyperlinks.Add Range("E1"),Replace(Range("E1").Hyperlinks(1).Address,
                              "google", "msn"), , , "newtext"
```